# Cocoa NSStatusItem image – opaque background

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, macos-sierra

I'm making a tiny menu bar app that shows the current iTunes song in the status bar. It works great, except for the fact that in dark mode, black areas of the album art show up the same color as the (transparent) menu bar background:

[image: transparent-status-item-bg]

Is there any way to make this be an opaque black background, instead?

---

On the white background, it makes white be the white transparent background, but black is a nice, deep black (overall I find this less annoying):

[image: transparent-status-item-bg-white]

Currently, I'm just using `[statusItem setImage:artworkImage]` to set the image.

Comment: Use NSAppearance.

Comment: On what, the status bar? Interesting—what would that do?

Comment: NSAppearance did work wonderfully on an image view inside the status item. Thanks, @ElTomato. (Now I just have to figure out how to get the click action!)

Comment: Apparently it doesn't work properly for multiple screens.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, adding a transparent NSView as a subview of the status item's button works wonderfully:

```
let subview = NSView.init(frame: statusItem!.button!.frame)
statusItem?.button?.addSubview(subview)
```

Now, I still have no idea *why* it works.

Edit: This works up to OS X v10.13 High Sierra, but **does not work on v10.14 Mojave**. It's back to transparency.